Is there a way to have Looker charts cross-filter when they use different datasets (although joined by a common UID)?
I have two source tables and two charts, and i want to have a Looker chart 2 to reflect a selection / filter in Looker chart 1
Table 1



Ticker
Total Val
Rating




ABCD
1,000
Silver


CDEF
2,000
Bronze



Table 2



Ticker
Region Val
Region




ABCD
1,000
USA


CDEF
500
EU


CDEF
500
UK


CDEF
500
USA


CDEF
500
APAC



If Table 1 --> Chart 1 and Table 2 --> Chart 2,
I'd like to select 'USA' region in Chart 2 so that Chart 1 (Filtered) looks like:
Chart 1 (Filtered)



Ticker
Total Val
Rating




ABCD
1,000
Silver


CDEF
500
Bronze



I've done this in PowerBI but not sure why I can't do it in Looker Studio
In Looker Studio:
I've tried joining the two tables and building reports from there, however this doesn't work when joining a third table, e.g. below:
Join Table 1 - works



Ticker
Region Val
Region
Rating




ABCD
1,000
USA
Silver


CDEF
500
EU
Bronze


CDEF
500
UK
Bronze


CDEF
500
USA
Bronze


CDEF
500
APAC
Bronze



Table 3



Ticker
Sector Val
Sector




ABCD
500
realestate


ABCD
500
utilities


CDEF
1,000
c_defensive


CDEF
1,000
healthcare



Join Table 1+Table 3 - doesn't work



Ticker
Region Val
Region
Rating
Sector Val
Sector




ABCD
1,000  X
USA
Silver
500 [OK]
utilities


ABCD
1,000  X
USA
Silver
500 [OK]
realestate


CDEF
500
EU
Bronze
?



CDEF
500
UK
Bronze
?



CDEF
500
USA
Bronze
?



CDEF
500
APAC
Bronze
?





I suspect its to do with the type of join you are using, please add, the type of join and what fields you are join with to the case above,
